# How to get the intellij version?

Tags: intellij-idea

I would like to automatize plugins installation from command line,chef,puppet,ansible ...

So for this I need to grab plugins archive from https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/ .

But to get a plugins archive I need to know what is the intellij version link to a given build

**Example with scala-plugins:**

archive are in https://plugins.jetbrains.com/files/1347/30658/
and for the intellij build number **163.4396—164**  it's  the version **2016.3.4**

So the url to download it is: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/files/1347/30658/scala-intellij-bin-**2016.3.4**.zip

**The problem:**

I can get build number by reading content of `$INTELLIJ_HOME/build.txt`

But how to know to which version this build number map ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: why not install well-known version of intellij together with plugins for this version?

Comment: scala-intellij-bin-2016.3.4.zip is the download URL for version 2016.3.4 of the Scala plugin. The version of the Scala plugin is not equal to the version of IntelliJ IDEA. (At this time, IntelliJ IDEA version 2016.3.4 does not exist.) The download URL for the plugin does not depend on the version of IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: @BartoszBilicki to have a maintainable system. when you need to install the same developer environment on computers you do not want to do it manually on each computer. You do not want to have a deploy system with hard coded version as next time you need to rewrite the deployment code.

Comment: @yole yes you are right 2016.3.4 of the Scala plugin is not related to a intellij version. So the main question left open. How to grab right version corresponding to a build number?

Comment: I completely undertand and agree with automation for installing tools. My idea was to somewhat change your requirements to achieve same result.
Rather than figuring out version of existing Idea and installing correct plugins, you could install Idea (with known version) and then install plugins for it. That way, to do not have to care about already-installed version.

Answer (score 15):

In the top bar where File, Edit, View... Are written, go to the Help section.
Click on Help section and in the drop-down click on About. That will show you the information regarding the Intellij Version you are using.

Answer (score 5):

Under the `Help` menu you can click `About`. Then you will see the IntelliJ version in the popup screen.

Answer (score 2):

For version 2020.3 on macOS:
You can find the 'About Intellij IDEA' at 'Intellij IDEA' tab drop-down which would describe the whole version like 2020.3.2 as for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In mac you can see it at the window during loading

[image]

Also in Help menu you can click `IntelliJ IDEA Help`

[image]

it opens a web page and in top left corner you can see a version

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, version number is present in file attributes
[image: file attributes for intelij version]